# Request Image file size

Tags: java, android, file

I have followed some tutorials about opening gallery and selecting and image and then displaying the image and file size. At the moment It doesnt seem to actually properly get the file size, i dont know if this is because of incorrect permissions or so on. Attached is the onCreate, openGallery and onActivityResult code.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    askPermission();
    imgOriginal = findViewById(R.id.imgOriginal);
    imgCompressed = findViewById(R.id.imgCompressed);
    txtOriginal = findViewById(R.id.txtOriginal);
    txtCompressed = findViewById(R.id.txtCompressed);
    txtQuality = findViewById(R.id.txtQuality);
    txtHeight = findViewById(R.id.txtHeight);
    txtWidth = findViewById(R.id.txtWidth);
    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekQuality);
    btnPick = findViewById(R.id.btnPick);
    btnCompress = findViewById(R.id.btnCompress);

    filepath = path.getAbsolutePath();

    if (!path.exists()) {
        path.mkdirs();
    }

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            txtQuality.setText("Quality: " + i);
            seekBar.setMax(100);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    btnPick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openGallery();

        }

    });
    btnCompress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int quality = seekBar.getProgress();
            int width = Integer.parseInt(txtWidth.getText().toString());
            //int height = Integer.parseInt(txtHeight.getText().toString());
            int height = Integer.parseInt(txtHeight.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Quality " + quality, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {


                compressedImage = new Compressor(MainActivity.this)
                        .setMaxWidth(width)
                        .setMaxHeight(height)
                        .setQuality(quality)
                        .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
                        .setDestinationDirectoryPath(filepath)
                        .compressToFile(originalImage);

                File finalFile = new File(filepath, originalImage.getName());
                Bitmap finalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(finalFile.getAbsolutePath());
                imgCompressed.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap);
                txtCompressed.setText("size: " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(MainActivity.this, finalFile.length()));
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, filepath + " Something went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error while Compressing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        }
    });
}
```

public void openGallery() {

```
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, RESULT_IMAGE);


    

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        btnCompress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        try {
            final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            imgOriginal.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);

            originalImage = new File(imageUri.getEncodedPath().replace("raw/", ""));
            txtOriginal.setText("Size: " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, originalImage.length()));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Size: " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, originalImage.length()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

This is my permissions code, this could be where i am wrong...The tutorial recommended to use Dexter, but any other ways or help with dexter would be appreciated.

```
private void askPermission() {
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        Dexter.withContext(this)
                .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {


            @Override
            public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport multiplePermissionsReport) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> list, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();

            }
        }).check();

    } else {

        Dexter.withContext(this)
                .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport multiplePermissionsReport) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> list, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK` You do not need any permission if you let the user pick a file with that intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
                        // There are no request codes
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                        if (isFileLessThan2MB(selectedImage)  <=    2000000){ // 2mp = 2000000
                            Glide.with(getContext()).load(selectedImage).into(binding.addressuploadImg);
                           addressuri =selectedImage;
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File Size Should below 2mp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }



 private long isFileLessThan2MB(Uri file) {
        Cursor returnCursor =
                getActivity().getContentResolver().query(file, null, null, null, null);
        /*
         * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
         * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
         * and display it.
         */
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
//
//        nameView.setText(returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
//        sizeView.setText(Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
        return returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The right way to get the file size for an Uri:

```
long size = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context,uri).length();
```

Comment: How would i correctly implement this into the code? displaying itas txtOriginal? Sorry im new to Java

Comment: Replace originalImage.length() in your code with size. Remove the line originalImage= and add the code above.

Comment: you also need to change uri to imageUri and context to this in my code.

Comment: It now crashes and i get this error     java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/151738 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.photocompressor/com.example.photocompressor.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: file

Comment: The trace will have the file name and line number where it happened. Check that place in your code for errors.

Comment: It says the long size line. maybe i incorrectly put in the uri.... how would u properly do that?

Comment: Could there be an error with my permissions code therefore it isnt accessing the selected photo properly?

Comment: long size = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this,imageUri).length();

Comment: Put it where the line originalImage = was.

Comment: It has nothing to do with permissions.

Comment: Hard to believe. It will not work for a media uri as you first showed. Only for a SAF uri.